# How to make a function to return the results of a prepared statement?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement

I am currently using this function to get categories data from mysql database.

```
function GetCategories()
    {
        $AryCategories = '';

            require("cnt.php"); // opening a connection.
            if($stmnt_get_categories = mysqli_prepare($con,'SELECT type_id,type_name FROM `tblpolltypes` order by type_name;'))
            {
                mysqli_stmt_execute($stmnt_get_categories);
                mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmnt_get_categories,$cat_id,$cat_name);
                while(mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmnt_get_categories))
                {
                    $AryCategories[$cat_id]=$cat_name;
                }
                mysqli_stmt_close($stmnt_get_categories);
            }
            mysqli_close($con);

        return $AryCategories;
    }
```

It is working fine but using this code means I am looping the returned array again which means processing the same data twice: 
the first: when I'm looping the statement results to store it in the array inside the function.
the second: when i'm looping the returned array to "echo" the data.

is there a better way to write this like returning the whole statement? or fetching the data directly in a multidimensional array without having to loop it?

Comment: You shouldn't connect in the every function call. On a live server you will kill your db server.

Comment: I wouldn't call it "tip" though. It's not something trifle but useless. Having connected only ONCE per application is rather one of most essential things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a better way to write this like returning the whole statement?

No.
There is nothing wrong with it, as long as you return only sane amount of data for the average web page.